# Unable to remove proxy from /etc/environment

Tags: proxy

I configure my proxy server using echo "http_proxy=http://proxyaddress:port" > /etc/environment, but now I'm unable to remove it from /etc/environment, kindly help me on this

Comment: In what way are you unable to remove it? What did you try, and what happened, exactly? Please [edit] your question to provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting or deleting a variable directs the shell to remove the variable from the list of variables that it tracks. Once you unset a variable, you cannot access the stored value in the variable.

Following is the syntax to unset a defined variable using the unset command:

> unset http_proxy=http://proxyaddress:port

Comment: Wouldn't `unset http_proxy` be sufficient?

Comment: I think it should work.

Comment: Or you can also comment out the proxy you need in /etc/environment

like this `#http_proxy=http://proxyaddress:port`

Comment: thank you so much it worked